# Youtube not displaying picture

Tags: firefox, youtube, adobe-flash

I am having problems viewing videos in firefox. it can play sound but the picture just seems to be black. I have uninstalled Flash and then reinstalled. It works for about 10 minutes then the picture goes again. I have done a few virus scans to check if there was any malicious software installed which came back clean. any ideas?

Comment: Is the screen saving kicking in? i.e. does the whole screen go black or just the video?

Comment: just the Video goes black the screen is still on and working. thing that makes it odd is bbc iplayer work properly but youtube doesnt

Comment: Are you using two screens?

Comment: no not using 2 screens

Comment: What operating system are you using? iPod Touch or Linux? I figure its gotta be one of these two.

Comment: im using windows xp firefox is the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify it in your question, but if you are using Firefox 4 Beta/RC then you might be the one of many victims of a common Firefox 4 bug, see [YouTube.com bug tracking](http://input.mozilla.com/en-US/release/site/http/youtube.com) on Mozilla.com

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the problem is there any fix out or just got to wait for mozilla to pull there finger out

Comment: You could try changing `http` to `https`, that fixes the problem for many users. Other than that you'll have to wait for a proper fix from Mozilla...